# How to make a background using CSS gradient with flat color?

Tags: css, gradient

A backgrond like this with same height of red and yellow.

[image]

Comment: check the examples [here](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/gradient/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using Colorzilla's [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffff00+30,ffff00+30,fe0000+30;Custom), just set two colors to the same % location and you'll get a hard edge between the two colors.

```
background: #ffff00; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00 30%, #ffff00 30%, #fe0000 30%); /*  FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(30%,#ffff00), color-stop(30%,#ffff00), color-stop(30%,#fe0000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00 30%,#ffff00 30%,#fe0000 30%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00 30%,#ffff00 30%,#fe0000 30%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffff00 30%,#ffff00 30%,#fe0000 30%); /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffff00', endColorstr='#fe0000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: linear-gradient(top, #ffff00 30%,#ffff00 30%,#fe0000 30%); /* W3C */
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for large heights in Chrome.  http://codepen.io/codecarson/pen/umesI

Answer (score 5):

Colorzilla's gradient generator is a nice start, but the code is awful in my opinion.
You'll never easily see if the colors are right, there's no output of short hex codes like `#ff0` and – most important in comparison to the answer above – the W3C standard has changed to [`to <side-or-corner>`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#linear-gradients).

So given your question after a flat gradient with *same* height of red and yellow area this is my preferred code:

```css
background-color: #ff0; /* Old browsers */
background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop( 50%, #ff0 ), color-stop( 50%, #ff0 ), color-stop( 50%, #fe0000 ) ); /* Chrome, Safari4+ */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( top, #ff0 50%, #ff0 50%, #fe0000 50% ); /* Chrome10+, Safari5.1+ */    
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( top, #ff0 50%, #ff0 50%, #fe0000 50% ); /* Fx3.6+ */   
background-image:         linear-gradient(      #ff0 50%, #ff0 50%, #fe0000 50% ); /* W3C */
```

[See example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/Volker_E/pen/eyKwd).

Also note, that you can leave out the deprecated `filter` property for IEs in this case, simply because there are no color stops included. 
If you know the exact height of the box, you could also work with `px` values instead of the `%` values for the color stops.

Updated 2016-01-16: *Neither `-o-` vendor prefix is necessary, nor `-ms-` (as IE 10 is the first IE to support gradients and it does support the W3C standards syntax)*. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients 
Updated 2016-01-27: Prefer [lowercase hex color values for better gzipping](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/lowercase/), and clearly state `background-color` and `background-image` instead of `background`. Also removed `to bottom` as it's the default value.