# Image reflection CSS not working in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, cross-browser

This is the current CSS I have to implement Image reflections (though applied to div tags which contain imagehyperlinks - fb and twitter) and it works in Chrome and Safari. How would I implement the same effect in IE9?

```
.SocialIconStyle
{

 width:27px; float:left;

-webkit-box-reflect: below 0
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), to(white)); 
}
```

[image: Image Reflection]

Comment: I also need a solution for firefox. Everything I found requires `-moz-element()` but in my case not every image has an id but all images can be styled with `#foo img`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE9s support for webkit style linear gradients is poor to say the least. Take a look here

[Does IE9 support CSS linear gradients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961651/does-ie9-support-css-linear-gradients)

You may be able to use svg using this site. Just check the IE9 support box.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/