# CSS3 Transition issue with radio button - IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, css, cross-browser, css-transitions

I am trying to create a radio button using CSS3 transition property. It works in all the major browsers except IE browsers. I am trying to make it work atleast from IE 9 .

I am aware IE 9 doesnot support css3 transitions. I would be glad to have any work around to make it work from ie 9.

http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/7ufZ4/8/

Comment: ie9 doesn't support transitions http://caniuse.com/css-transitions

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961651/does-ie9-support-css-linear-gradients

Comment: I have already taken care of linear gradient issue . cheers Diodeus