# Styles.php Conditional PHP / CSS not working in IE 9

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, background-image

I have a style.php setup which is being called using this code:

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/css/styles.php');?>
```

This style sheet contains this code:

```
<?php $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'title-image', true);
$thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0]; ?>

<style>

/* GET FEATURED IMAGE FOR TITLE BACKGROUND */
.titlearea {
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('<?php echo $thumb_url ?>');
<?php else: ?>
background: url('http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/my-custom-theme/includes/images/services-top.jpg');
<?php endif; ?>
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 0;
}
</style>
```

Which should look for a post thumbnail (im using Wordpress) and display that as the background image if there is one, if the page doesnt have a thumbnail then it should fallback to the default (services-top.jpg).

This code is working great in Chome and Firefox but IE9 is just showing a white background, its not even registering the fallback defautl image.

Anyone know why this isnt working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer @Mooseman

Your answer helped and I got the style functioning as wanted with this code:

```
.titlearea {
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
    /*IE7-*/ background:            url('http://example.com/default.jpg');
    /*IE8+*/ background:            url('http://example.com/default.jpg');
    background:                     -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('<?php echo $thumb_url ?>');
    background:                     -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('<?php echo $thumb_url ?>');
    background:                     -ms-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('<?php echo $thumb_url ?>');
    background:                     -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('<?php echo $thumb_url ?>');
    background:                     linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('<?php echo $thumb_url ?>');
<?php else: ?>
    background:                     url('http://example.com/default.jpg');
<?php endif; ?>
    background-size:                cover;
    background-position:            50% 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP runs on the server. Your issue is that IE9 does not support `linear-gradient`. Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745402/1234256):

> The best cross-browser solution is
>
> ```
> background: #fff;
> background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #000);
> background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #000);
> background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #000);
> background: -ms-linear-gradient(#fff, #000);/*For IE10*/
> background: linear-gradient(#fff, #000);
> filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000');/*For IE7-8-9*/ 
> height: 1%;/*For IE7*/
> ```